# Asian airline with free 24-hour refunds?

Tags: bookings, airlines, refunds, proof-of-onward-travel, asia

I could buy a ticket from Asia to the US and get a full refund within 24 hours, but does anyone know of any Asian airline with shorter regional flights or a booking website that would allow me to use it for making a cheap booking as proof of onward travel?

Comment: Note: It is not considered as an important *proof* (as you see, you may get refunds, etc.). Also if you do it, use use it as proof and they find you cancelled within 24 hours, it may be considered criminal act (if the intention was to cheap the officers). As I learned from various US consular officers: nobody expect you commit to a flight before getting a visa (which can take a long time). (and if it is for a return flight, see the risk above).

Comment: Note that some countries like China do not actually like things like that at all and it can get you banned (see last paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_mainland_China?#72-hour_stay_/_144-hour_stay)

Answer (score 0):

Asiana. See https://flyasiana.com/C/US/EN/contents/ticket-information for details on the refund policy (depends on ticket class, departure date, etc.)